# How do I associate my Superuser and Serverfault accounts to my CV?

Tags: support

I noticed that some people have their Superuser and Serverfault profile on the right column of their CV.  I can only see my Stackoverflow profile, how do I add those other two?

Comment: You use Google as your Open ID provider don't you?

Comment: Yes, and it only show my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: when you publish, it should show all of them

Comment: Google Open ID hashes for each new site, so it won't be automatic from the start on Careers.

Comment: Issue described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/i-hate-google-openid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to associate your accounts with each-other.

Once you do that, all of them that you associate will show up.

If you have over 200 rep points, on at least one of the sites, you will will get a 100 rep point bonus on all of the sites, that you have associated.

Comment: That's not right; I have 1,100 + on serverfault. I got the 100 for superuser but not for SO.

Comment: I think it depends on which site you associate them from.

Comment: There was another question about this.